# Aurelia router navigation to route on same machine different application

Tags: aurelia

I'd like to make aurelia's router navigate to a route that is in a different application, but hosted on the same machine/port/etc. Is this possible without an absolute URL?

i.e:

we are here -> http://somedomain.com/#/foo

i want the router to go here -> http://somedomain.com/app2/#/foo

what I do not want to do is hard code the http://somedomain.com/app2 I'd prefer to be able to do:

```
this.router.navigate('/app2');
```

and not have it treat the /app2 as a route within the current app. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think the router can recognise a route that doesn't belong to the application

Comment: I suspect you will have to use actual HTTP routing rather than the Aurelia router, since the Aurelia router is designed to use within the same application.  You could still create a global singular that has the absolute path coded only 1 time and then any specific routing paths could be relative to it, like `url = baseUrl + '/#/foo';`.

Comment: Here's how you would do it using Javascript:
`document.location.href = baseUrl + '/#/foo';`

Comment: so after plowing through the code you guys appear to be correct. the problem is there is no option to tell the aurelia router that the passed route is absolute vs relative fragment so when a domain origin are not included it assumes it is a route fragment within the application.  it would be nice to tell the router to treat it as an absolute url